# Is it ok to have JSONP request inside JSONP?

Tags: javascript, json, jsonp

Is the following code legal?

```
$.getJSON(server_url+"?callback=?",{id:deleteId,pw:password,action:"editpassword"},function(data){

            $.getJSON(server_url+"?callback=?",     {id:deleteId,pw:password,action:"editpassword"},function(data){

});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, why not.

I have nothing much to add, except - the callback function can do whatever it wants, including making another server request.

Answer (score 0):

Still from your example it's not understandable why you could want it.

If you are generating the second request based on the data received in the first request that's not quite good for performance reasons because the same thing could be done on the server side with one request only. Such nested solution makes the user to wait more.